# Chrome: menu items are not visible anymore

Tags: html, css

For some reason the white menu items of this website: www.danydiop.com disappeared in Chrome from one day to another one.

How is that possible ? Is because of a Chrome update ?

thanks

Comment: Lots of 0 height elements, perhaps a floating issue?

Comment: Testing in Chrome dev channel, I have the described problem. The answer posted by Sotiris resolves it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to change

```
#block-menu-primary-links {
line-height: 0px;
}
```

to

```
#block-menu-primary-links {
line-height: 1px;
}
```